# Member of db_datareader database role

Tags: sql-server

I'm not the member of db_datareader database role but still I'm able to do select operation on tables. In which scenario it is required to add users to this role? 
How is it possible to do select operations without being the member of db_datareader?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a member of another role with `select` granted for the object, you can do the select.  db_datareader is a fixed role that bypasses select grants (you cannot revoke select for a user with db_datareader).

Comment: What are the other possible roles that can grant select permission? Does the role gives this permission by default?

Comment: Your administrator should be able to tell you by what mechanism you have the permissions that you do. One thing you can do by yourself is `select * from sys.user_token` to see what roles you are a member of in the database. That may provide clue enough!

Comment: To see what permissions have been assigned in a database, I use this:  `SELECT     coalesce(Obj.type_desc, class_desc) as Type, coalesce(Obj.name, db_name()) AS What, [Perm].state_desc, [Perm].permission_name, who.name AS who
FROM         sys.database_permissions AS [Perm] INNER JOIN
         sys.database_principals AS who ON [Perm].grantee_principal_id = who.principal_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sys.all_objects AS Obj ON [Perm].major_id = Obj.object_id
WHERE     ([Perm].major_id >= 0) and (Obj.is_ms_shipped = 0 or class_desc = 'DATABASE')
order by class, type, who.name`